# Create white noise wav using Python

Tags: python, random, noise

I need to create a programme in Python that uses following inputs:

- A specific length for a noise segment A.
- A specific length for a noise segment B.
- A specific length for a noise segment C.
- A specific length for a noise segment interval (I) that may either be always different when sequenced within ABC or be just empty (silent).

A, B, C however are for themselves constant throughout the sequenced file, I is always different each time when called upon.

I then just give the program a sequence (e.g. ABCIABIABCI) using an interface that I have already written using tkinter and the Programm spits out a single wav file which glued together the white noise segments in the order I defined.

Any ideas what I could use?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: if A and B are white noise, then how does AB differ from BA? Volume?

Comment: Hi Peter, good point. The thing is... A ist created randomly, as well as B. Throughout the totality of the wav file, the A segment is always the same, as well as B. Thus AB is not the same as BA... The point for my thesis is are we able to distinguish these pattern given our sensory auditive memory... Does that make sense?